# emacs does not see my fonts in gentoo

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, fonts, gentoo

I copied my ~/.emacs file from ubuntu linux; I've installed Consolas font (and it works in gnome terminal, and as a default Monospace font); but Emacs does not see it

```
(custom-set-faces '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 98 :width normal :foundry "microsoft" :family "Consolas"))) t))
```

That's how I set the font in emacs, but it does not work (It worked and still works in Ubuntu)

What can I do?

Font select menu (menu-set-font, I guess) looks very strange, consists of three options: Misc, Courier and Fontset, and there are no sign of my system fonts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Gilles said, to use a TrueType font like Consolas in Emacs 23 you must link it with the Freetype and Fontconfig libraries. In Gentoo, you do that by turning on the `xft` [USE flag](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/USE) when building Emacs.  You'll need to turn that flag on (either globally or just for app-editors/emacs) and reinstall Emacs.

Comment: thanks! awesome! looking into USE flags solved not only this problem with emacs, thank you very much

Comment: @valya, because it builds things from source and provides use flags, Gentoo is much more customizable than distros like Ubuntu.  The downside is that it's easy to leave out a feature that it turns out you actually do want.  Fortunately, that's usually not too hard to fix; you just adjust your use flags and reinstall whatever program is missing a feature.

Comment: It's okay then the app is small, but I sometimes had to leave my computer building (or re-building) certain things while I'm asleep, because it took hours

Answer (score 3):

Support for TrueType fonts such as your Consolas font — more generally, support for client-rendered fonts — requires Emacs to be compiled against the Freetype and Fontconfig libraries. This was introduced in Emacs 23. Before, only traditional, server-rendered fonts were supported. See [the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html) for more information about the two kinds of fonts and how to use them.